# Using jssc in android studio

Tags: java, android, jssc

Downloaded jssc and added it to my project in android studio.

```
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM1");
    try {
        if (sp!=null && sp.isOpened ()) {
            sp.closePort();
        }
        try{
            sp.openPort();
            sp.setParams(9600,8,1,0);
        }catch (Error f){
            Log.d("Trace", f.getMessage());
        }
        sp.closePort();
    }catch (SerialPortException e){
        Log.d("Trace", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Tried running this as a static function from my onCreate function.

On sp.openPort() I get the error

*No implementation found for long jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(java.lang.String, boolean) (tried Java_jssc_SerialNativeInterface_openPort and Java_jssc_SerialNativeInterface_openPort__Ljava_lang_String_2Z)*

I've already made a SSh connection with jsch and to open the socket I had to make a new thread. Didn't work when I did it for jssc.

When I run through Putty I connect using COM1.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

After some more debugging I've found that this:

```
String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
```

Doesn't display any ports.

If I go to Device manager in Ports I can now see COM1 and COM4.

Any advice?

Comment: You have to import JSSC as NDK to make this work with Android.

Comment: Thanks @ShekharKG. I had kind of left this project as I was pulling my hair out over it. I will definetly go back and have a look at this. Thanks again

Comment: @ShekharKG do you have more information how to proceed to import jssc as NDK?